# ERROR ReferenceError: google is not defined Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 8 and have been trying to get the Google Maps API to function. The error I get in the console is `ERROR ReferenceError: google is not defined`. I have proofread over my code a myriad of times. I've already changed the double quote on the URL for the API. The guides I followed were:

https://medium.com/@jkeung/integrating-google-maps-api-w-angular-7-e7672396ce2d and https://medium.com/@balramchavan/integrating-google-maps-in-angular-5-ca5f68009f29.

The following section is the code I used to modify the files.

---

HTML component file:

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=(The API key I used went here)"></script>
```

Component TypeScript File:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {} from 'googlemaps';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-about-me',
    templateUrl: './about-me.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./about-me.component.scss']
})
export class AboutMeComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('map', { static: true }) mapElement: any;
    map: google.maps.Map;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        const mapProperties = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.2271, -80.8431),
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapProperties);
    }
}
```

---

The `index.d.ts` file:

```js
declare module 'googlemaps';
```

---

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-angular-site",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.4",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.23",
    "bulma": "^0.7.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.11.2",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.38.1",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

---

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
"extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [
      "googlemaps"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You have run the npm command? `npm install --save @types/googlemaps`

Comment: Have you tried using HTTPS? ```"https://maps.googleapis.com...```

Comment: according to the documents for the [@google/maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google/maps) package. you will need to install `npm install @types/google__maps` you will need the double _

Comment: @daddygames Yes, I have already run the command previously.

Comment: @nullptr.t Yes, I have already tried using HTTPS.

Comment: @JoeJazdzewski I ran the command you gave me but nothing has really changed.

Comment: can you add your package.json file?

Comment: did you restart your application?

Comment: Post your tsconfig.app

Comment: try adding **declare var google;** above AboutMeComponent

Comment: Same issue. Have you found a solution?